# JS Filter Object that includes array

Tags: javascript

I tried to filter a JS object that includes an array. I want to check if `id`, `matchcode` and `description`. That was I tried was that:

```
    let search = articles.filter(function(item){
      return (item.matchcode.includes(articleno) || item.description.includes(articleno) || item.id.includes(articleno))
    })
```

That is the object:

```
let articles = '[ {
        "id": "35",
        "matchcode": "KM Anteile  S",
        "description": "KM Anteile  S ",
        "unit": "STK",
        "salesPrice": 0.7,
        "stock": "HL-F",
        "stockAmount": -3282
    },
    {
        "id": "41",
        "matchcode": "Arbeitszeit",
        "description": "Arbeitszeit ",
        "unit": "STD",
        "salesPrice": 76.8,
        "stock": "HL-F",
        "stockAmount": 0.75
    }, {
        "id": "502019",
        "matchcode": "Gummimuffe 100 mm",
        "description": "Gummimuffe 100 mm ",
        "unit": "STK",
        "salesPrice": 9.8,
        "stock": "HL-F",
        "stockAmount": 15
    }';
```

When I tried it, I get the error, that `filter` is not an function.

Comment: `articles` is a string.  You need to `JSON.parse()` it.

Comment: Your `articles` value is a (syntactically invalid) **string**, not an `object`-graph. You need to run it through `JSON.parse` first. Also, JS strings using single `'` or double-quotes `"` cannot contain literal newlines unless they're template-strings (backticks), but your `let articles` value is using single-quotes _and_ contains literal newlines, which will simply fail to run because the parser will reject it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let articles = [ {
            "id": "35",
            "matchcode": "KM Anteile  S",
            "description": "KM Anteile  S ",
            "unit": "STK",
            "salesPrice": 0.7,
            "stock": "HL-F",
            "stockAmount": -3282
        },
        {
            "id": "41",
            "matchcode": "Arbeitszeit",
            "description": "Arbeitszeit ",
            "unit": "STD",
            "salesPrice": 76.8,
            "stock": "HL-F",
            "stockAmount": 0.75
        }, {
            "id": "502019",
            "matchcode": "Gummimuffe 100 mm",
            "description": "Gummimuffe 100 mm ",
            "unit": "STK",
            "salesPrice": 9.8,
            "stock": "HL-F",
            "stockAmount": 15
        }];
    let articleno = "Gummimuffe"
    let search = articles.filter(function(item){
          return (item.matchcode.includes(articleno) || item.description.includes(articleno) || item.id.includes(articleno))
        })
        console.log(search)
```

This is a sample example, which you can apply to your code as well.

```js
let arr = JSON.parse('[{"value":"This is object insided array"}]');
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to close your `[` with `]` and you have a string, not an array of objects. You can also use `JSON.parse()`. This would do the job:

```
let articles = [{
        "id": "35",
        "matchcode": "KM Anteile  S",
        "description": "KM Anteile  S ",
        "unit": "STK",
        "salesPrice": 0.7,
        "stock": "HL-F",
        "stockAmount": -3282
    },
    {
        "id": "41",
        "matchcode": "Arbeitszeit",
        "description": "Arbeitszeit ",
        "unit": "STD",
        "salesPrice": 76.8,
        "stock": "HL-F",
        "stockAmount": 0.75
    }, {
        "id": "502019",
        "matchcode": "Gummimuffe 100 mm",
        "description": "Gummimuffe 100 mm ",
        "unit": "STK",
        "salesPrice": 9.8,
        "stock": "HL-F",
        "stockAmount": 15
    }
];
```

Additional thing is that `.filter()` returns a new array while keeping original one as it is.

Answer (score 2):

Because `articles` is a string you need to parse it by using `JSON.parse()`,

---

Note: as @Dai mentioned in the comment in this question `includes()` is case sensitive, so you might want to use  another approach in order to have a friendly search  (case insensitive)

I choosed to use  `new RegExp()` and instead of `includes()` I used `match()`

```js
const articles = `[ {
"id": "35",
"matchcode": "KM Anteile  S",
"description": "KM Anteile  S ",
"unit": "STK",
"salesPrice": 0.7,
"stock": "HL-F",
"stockAmount": -3282
}, {
  "id": "41",
  "matchcode": "Arbeitszeit",
  "description": "Arbeitszeit ",
  "unit": "STD",
  "salesPrice": 76.8,
  "stock": "HL-F",
  "stockAmount": 0.75
}, {
  "id": "502019",
  "matchcode": "Gummimuffe 100 mm",
  "description": "Gummimuffe 100 mm ",
  "unit": "STK",
  "salesPrice": 9.8,
  "stock": "HL-F",
  "stockAmount": 15
}]
`;
const articlenenoFilter = "arbeitsze"

const articleneno = new RegExp(articlenenoFilter, "i")

const search = JSON.parse(articles).filter((item) => (item.matchcode.match(articleneno) || item.description.match(articleneno) || item.id.match(articleneno)))

console.log(search)
```

Comment: I note that `String.prototype.includes` is case-sensitive, which probably isn't what the OP wants (as it looks like they want to do human-friendly searching, which should be case-insensitive and probably support fuzzy-searching too).

Comment: ya good point,  including `toLowerCase()`  before `includes` probably will do

Comment: Using `toLowerCase` like that isn't far from ideal though... that's going to cause a lot of (relatively expensive) string allocations....

Comment: @Dai I've updated the answer to use regex and `match`